# Woocommerce Admin - Update Search to get closest matching titles inside Add Product modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

When manually creating an order in the **Woocommerce** Admin there is an option to search for products to tie to the order. I want to limit the results here to the products with the **closest matching titles**  and ignore anything relating to the product descriptions.

I noticed the form makes an ajax call to the woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations function each time it retrieves the results however I am not sure how to override this to achieve the functionality i want.

[image: Woocommerce Admin->Create Order->Product Search*]

*Any help is greatly appreciated.*